# Determine Final Destination of a Shortened URL in PHP?

Tags: php, url-routing, bit.ly

How can I do this in PHP? e.g.

bit.ly/f00b4r ==> http://www.google.com/search?q=cute+kittens

In Java, the solution is this:

> You should issue a HEAD request to
>   the url using a HttpWebRequest
>   instance. In the returned
>   HttpWebResponse, check the
>   ResponseUri.
>
> Just make sure the AllowAutoRedirect
>   is set to true on the HttpWebRequest
>   instance (it is true by default).
>   (Thx, casperOne)

And the code is

```
private static string GetRealUrl(string url)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    return response.ResponseUri.ToString();
}
```

(Thx, Fredrik Mork)

But I want to do it in PHP. HOWTO? :)

Comment: do you need this for an specific shortener ? or you are just talking in general? many of the "good" shorteners can provide you the final destination when calling via API

Comment: FYI:
If you are trying to get http://t.co twitter urls to redirect they give a 200 response code so you have to grab the `<noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://tinyurl.com/7ktoegq"></noscript><script>location.replace("http:\/\/tinyurl.com\/7ktoegq")</script>` from the body.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CREDIT GOES TO http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/curl-get-final-url-after-inital-url-redirects-544144.html

```
function get_web_page( $url ) 
{ 
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // return headers 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
    ); 

    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
    curl_close( $ch ); 

    //$header['errno']   = $err; 
   // $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg; 
    //$header['content'] = $content; 
    print($header[0]); 
    return $header; 
}  
$thisurl = "http://www.example.com/redirectfrom";
$myUrlInfo = get_web_page( $thisurl ); 
echo $myUrlInfo["url"];
```

Answer (score 6):

*The time to try, you already found the answer.*

Still, I would have gone with something like this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://bit.ly/tqdUj");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);

$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($url);
```

Some explanations :

- the requested URL is the short one
- you don't want the headers
- you want to make sure the body is not displayed -- probably useless
- you do not want the body ; ie, you want a HEAD request, and not GET
- you want locations to be followed, of course
- once the request has been executed, you want to get the "real" URL that has been fetched

And, here, you get :

```
string 'http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pubsubhubbub/' (length=52)
```

*(Comes from one of the last tweets I saw that contained a short URL)*

This should work with any shortening-URL service, independantly of their specific API.

You might also want to tweak some other options, like timeouts ; see [curl_setopt](http://php.net/curl_setopt) for more informations.

Comment: I've tried a few things on t.co twitter links and this is the only thing that has worked for me so far. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

print_r(get_headers($url));

print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
?>
```

Comment: Parsing the Location header would probably work ; but what if there is tow (or more) levels of redirections ? (yeah, not what you generally see, but what if the destination site sets up some redirections the day they release a new version of the site ? )

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the bit.ly API? specifically [here](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/expand) ?

I can't see the issue. Are you talking about possible redirects ?

Comment: If using a specific API, you will have to create a new specific code for each distinct shortening-URL service ; considering there are quite a bit of those, you will never stop coding and testing... some "generic" solution that work with any service would probably be easier, at least as a long term solution...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I coded it, because none of the above worked correctly.

```
function get_final_location($url, $index=null) {

    if (is_array($url)) {
        $headers = $url;
    }
    else {
        $headers = get_headers($url, 1)['Location'];    
        if (count($headers) == 0) {
            return $url;
        }
    }

    if (is_null($index)) {
        $to_check   = end($headers);
        $index      = count($headers) - 1;
    }
    else {
        $to_check = $headers[$index];
    }

    if (!filter_var($to_check, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
        if (count($headers) - 1 > $index) {
            $lp = parse_url($headers[$index], PHP_URL_SCHEME) . "://" . parse_url($headers[$index], PHP_URL_HOST) . $headers[$index+1];
        }
        else {
            $lp = $to_check;
        }
    }
    else {
        $index--;
        $lp = landingpage($headers, $index);
    }

    return $lp;

}
```