# Display video or image from shorten URL

Tags: javascript, html

How to display properly a shortened URL which can hold either video or image file? The URL does not contain extension and the domain can be of different origin. I need to use either video or image tag depending on the source type so it is rendered correctly by browser. The solution can be with JavaScript or markup.

Example:
[IMAGE] http://bit.ly/1uI7Ddj
[VIDEO] http://bit.ly/1vvkYJ1

I tried following but it doesn't work as expected:

```
<video width="300" height="150" src="http://bit.ly/1uI7Ddj">
    <img width="300" height="150" src="http://bit.ly/1uI7Ddj" alt="Fallback if video is not playing" />
</video>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine Final Destination of a Shortened URL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319621/determine-final-destination-of-a-shortened-url-in-php)

Comment: @skobaljic, I've added tags for HTML5 and JavaScript. I'm not interesed in PHP solution.

Comment: I see, and when I spend half an hour to help you, you do not even read the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible unless you own the domain where you want the shortened URL.  For example, to do that, you would need to own (or have access to) the website bit.ly.

bit.ly is not hosting your video or your image, it only redirects them to the real URL when you click on the link.

The source code from your bit.ly can be found here on chrome: view-source:http://bit.ly/1uI7Ddj

You will see that your image is NOT in the code.  It only redirects to the page that DOES contain your image.

Answer (score 0):

To get full URL on **bit.ly**, you need to register to developers API and [create an app](http://dev.bitly.com/my_apps.html), than you can use [expand method](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_expand).

For **goo.gl** short links, sing in with Google account and register to API, and use [expand method](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#expand).

But **best** in your case would be **[longurl.org API](http://longurl.org/api)**, which has a simple method to expand URLs. Take a look at their [expand-url documentation](http://longurl.org/api#expand-url).

An example request to their API:

```
GET http://api.longurl.org/v2/services&format=json
```

and since you do not want to use PHP, than you need to ask for jsonp format this way:

```
GET http://api.longurl.org/v2/services&format=json&callback=foo&user-agent=Application-Name%2F3.7
```

So, alltogether, you need to expand url and get json this way:

```
GET http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1uI7Ddj&format=json&callback=foo&user-agent=Application-Name%2F3.7
```

You get response:

```
foo({"long-url":"http:\/\/flark.it\/f\/i\/1884680242.WP_000008.jpg"})
```

Similar with `jsonp`, [read more about jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp#5943630)

There is also [expandURL API](http://expandurl.appspot.com/), but I do not see they offer jsonp responses. Example there would be:

```
GET http://expandurl.appspot.com/expand?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1uI7Ddj
```

and you get json response:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "end_url": "http://flark.it/f/i/1884680242.WP_000008.jpg",
    "redirects": 1,
    "urls": ["http://bit.ly/1uI7Ddj",
    "http://flark.it/f/i/1884680242.WP_000008.jpg"],
    "start_url": "http://bit.ly/1uI7Ddj"
}
```